# This poem is complete, except the solution to it

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, poetry

> First, hide the text, come on, no spoilers here;
>
> Second, bash at it, you have nothing to fear;
>
> Third, pair up and basic pigpen, flagging every time;
>
> Fourth, use the force, wait, no, rather a rhyme?
>
> Fifth, flip from left to right, come on, you're almost done;
>
> Sixth, where is number six, is it a free one?
>
> Last, come on, you're almost there, have chemistry with me;
>
> Finally, the answer is lflflflfljffljljljlflffflfljljljljmflflflfljljffljlflflflfmflfljljljljfflflfljljljmfljljljlflfljljljljljmfljljljljljfflfljljljlj

#### Hint 1:

> Bash at, at bash, that's a clue for five less three; 
>  but you still have to clear them chronologically.

#### Hint 2:

> okay, okay, a clue for number one, 
>  partial answers in the comments when you're still not done; 
>  furthermore, a clue for one plus two, 
>  the pigpen shows the pattern of the flags for you

Comment: first thoughts ROT13: Lbh zragvba cvtcra fb V'z nffhzvat fbzr xvaq bs cvtcra pvcure? V nyfb abgvprq gung gur bayl 5 yrggref hfrq va gur "nafjre" ner W,V,Y,Z (juvpu ner neenatrq ba n djregl xrlobneq va n phefbe-yvxr funcr) naq S. Gurl erzvaq zr n ybg bs hc,qbja,yrsg,evtug naq sver xrlf lbh zvtug cynl n tnzr jvgu. Be, vg pbhyq or gb qb jvgu znexvat bhg gur funcr bs gur cvtcra pvcure?

Comment: i love this, and even more when i see the answer. +1 to both and a star to the question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, let me say thank you for this great riddle.

My answer is

> Binary

Here are my steps:

### 1. First, hide the text, come on, no spoilers here;

Explanation:

> First thoughts were the spoiler Tag >! but we got Hint2:
>
>  *okay, okay, a clue for number one,*
>  ***partial answers in the comments*** *when you're still not done;*
>
>  How are we hiding text in comments? We use **[Rot13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13)**, a Ceasar Cipher with Shift 13!

Lets do it:

> We start decrypting:
>  rot13(lflflflfljffljljljlflffflfljljljljmflflflfljljffljlflflflfmflfljljljljfflflfljljljmfljljljlflfljljljljljmfljljljljljfflfljljljlj) =
>  **ysysysysywssywywywysysssysywywywywzsysysysywywssywysysysyszsysywywywywssysysywywywzsywywywysysywywywywywzsywywywywywssysywywywyw**

### 2. Second, bash at it, you have nothing to fear;

Explanation:

> First thoughts were some characters used in bash-scripts #! but we got Hint1:
>
>  *Bash at, **at bash**, that's a clue for five less three;
>
>  but you still have to clear them chronologically.*
>
>  So we know the next Cipher: **[Atbash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atbash)** (A->Z , B->Y ... Z->A)

Lets do it:

> We continue decrypting:
>  atbash(ysysysysywssywywywysysssysywywywywzsysysysywywssywysysysyszsysywywywywssysysywywywzsywywywysysywywywywywzsywywywywywssysywywywyw) =
>  **bhbhbhbhbdhhbdbdbdbhbhhhbhbdbdbdbdahbhbhbhbdbdhhbdbhbhbhbhahbhbdbdbdbdhhbhbhbdbdbdahbdbdbdbhbhbdbdbdbdbdahbdbdbdbdbdhhbhbdbdbdbd**

### 3. Third, pair up and basic pigpen, flagging every time;

Explanation:

> a) Pair Up: Take two letters at once, makes 64 pairs
>  b) basic pigpen: in **[pigpen cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigpen_cipher)** we place the letters into something like #
>  c) Lookup the pairs in the pigpen structure, interpreting the positions as 2 flags (**[semaphore cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_semaphore)**)
>  d) Write the Flags as letters

Lets do it:

> a) bh bh bh bh bd hh bd bd bd bh bh hh bh bd bd bd bd ah bh bh bh bd bd hh bd bh bh bh bh ah bh bd bd bd bd hh bh bh bd bd bd ah bd bd bd bh bh bd bd bd bd bd ah bd bd bd bd bd hh bh bd bd bd bd
>  This gives 4 distinct pairs to decode: bh, bd, hh, ah
>  b) create the basic pigpen (we only need the first #, cause our letters are a,b,d and h):
>  [image: Basic PigPen structure]
>  c) place the four pairs in the pigpen as follows
>  [image: PigPen bh]  [image: PigPen bd]  [image: PigPen hh]  [image: PigPen ah]
>  d) lookup the flag-codes
>  bh = [image: flag bh] = D
>  bd = [image: flag bd] = P
>  hh = [image: flag hh]  = space/break _
>  ah = [image: flag ah] = C
>
>  which finally gives us **DDDDP_PPPDD_DPPPPCDDDPP_PDDDDCDPPPP_DDPPPCPPPDDPPPPPCPPPPP_DPPPP**

### 4. Fourth, use the force, wait, no, rather a rhyme?

Explanation

> My first thought was a rhyme on "the force" is "semaphores" so I missed the real step because I used semaphores already in the last step
>  Then I tried "force" -> "morse" as pointed out by @oryxandcake in a comment
>  Well, how to do some **[morse code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code)** on DDDDP_PPPDD....?
>  D could be **D**ash, P could be **P**oint, _ and C are separators for chars and words

Lets do it:

> Convert DDDDP_PPPDD_DPPPPCDDDPP_PDDDDCDPPPP_DDPPPCPPPDDPPPPPCPPPPP_DPPPP to morse code:
>  ----. ...-- -..../---.. .----/-.... --.../...--...../..... -....
>  I used " " for "__" and "/" for "C"
>  the blocks of 5 Symbols (_ and .) point us to numbers, so it decode as:
>  **936/81/67/35/56**

### 5. Fifth, flip from left to right, come on, you're almost done;

Explanation:

> Easy one, just flip it around

Lets do it:

> flip(936/81/67/35/56) = **65/53/76/18/639**

### 6. Sixth, where is number six, is it a free one?

Explanation:

> Kick out those sixes

Lets do it:

> 65/53/76/18/639 -> **5/53/7/18/39**

### 7. Last, come on, you're almost there, have chemistry with me;

Explanation:

> Lookup those numbers in the [periodic table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table)

Lets do it:

> 5 -> Boron -> B
>  53 -> Iodine -> I
>  7 -> Nitrogen -> N
>  18 -> Argon -> Ar
>  39 -> Yttrium -> Y
>  --> **Binary**

### 8. Finally, the answer is lflflflfljffljljljlflffflfljljljljmflflflfljljffljlflflflfmflfljljljljfflflfljljljmfljljljlflfljljljljljmfljljljljljfflfljljljlj

Explanation:

> Replace the string with our decoded one and check if it rhymes

Lets do it:

> Finally, the answer is *binary*
>  rhymes with the ending of line 7 (have chemistry with *me*)
>  Looks correct.

Comment: This is insanely brilliant. Well done!!

Answer (score 2):

Partial:

*First, hide the text, come on, no spoilers here;*

> The symbols used to create spoilers here are >!

*Second, bash at it, you have nothing to fear;*

> In bash scripts, they often start with #!

*Third, pair up and basic pigpen, flagging every time;*

> The symbols > and # look like they're in pigpen form, maybe the ! means to add the dots to them. Assuming # means all of the letters in the # format, this translates to: **XJKLMNOPQR**

*Fourth, use the force, wait, no, rather a rhyme?*

> Thanks to @oryxandcake, this step involves using morse code (a rhyme of force).

*Fifth, flip from left to right, come on, you're almost done;*

> Pretty self explanatory to just reverse the order of what you have.

*Sixth, where is number six, is it a free one?*

> Not sure without getting this far, perhaps replacing a 6 with 31

*Last, come on, you're almost there, have chemistry with me;*

> Maybe, if step 6 uses numbers, we'd have numbers now, and this clue means to get the chemical symbols with atomic numbers that we have and it will form a word.

Comment: Second should be `#!` not `!#`? Though it's not just bash, a lot of scripting languages (python, perl, etc.) make use of this construct

Comment: @ace you're right, I've only ever seen it used with bash, will edit it in

Comment: For the fourth step... rot13(zbefr)?

Comment: @oryxandcake oooh yes